# Make the condition to hide header on child pages Wordpess

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I ran into the problem of hiding the header on the pages of a particular directory on WordPress CMS.

Is it possible to make an php-code condition that will be do not show the header on all pages in some directory by condition:

like

```
<?php if( $some_page => have 'users' in $url ) : ?>
    <header style="display:none"></header>
<?php else......
<?php endif....
```

P.S.

I know about a great pluging for css magic on any page, but I have a too many pages...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: `body:not(.home/index/whatever) .page-header { display: none; }` something like this might work using css, although your theme needs to make use of `<body <?php body_class(); ?>> `

Comment: I recommend not to do this with css. Write a function which checks for your required condition. If that function returns true load the header otherwise do not load. Doing display none may hide the element but still that element is rendered. But if you do that with php it won't render in pages which you don't want to show it.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC thanks for explanation. But I need not an explanation (I know it like and you), I need the working solution. And I already make it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution for this:

We can make a simple search in the url on the symbol or phrase in it, by `stristr()` func. So the condition will be next:

```
<?php $current_page = get_page_link() ?>

<?php if (stristr($current_page, "user") == true) : ?>              // if "url" have 
    <h1 class="entry-title h1" style="display:none;"></h1>          // phrase 'user' 
<?php else : ?>                                                     // in it the header will not show
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title h1">', '</h1>' ); ?>   // header 
    <h1 class="entry-title h1"></h1>                                // show without any problem
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solution**

Lets say your homepage `body` class : `<body class="index">` and your header `<header class="page-header">text</header>`

You could use this class for displaying header or not , using this method.

```
body:not(.index) .page-header { display: none; }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some edits in your answer.

```
    <?php $current_page = get_page_link() ?>

    <?php if (stristr($current_page, "user") === false) : ?> 
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title h1">', '</h1>' ); ?>   
    <?php endif; ?>
//If you don't want to render anything on true condition no need to render anything.
```

Use `===` for checking the types as well.